# RTF text font/color changing

Tags: c#, winforms

The main idea is to change the text inside RichTextBox to the chosen Font/Color from the Color&FontDialog, this was simple for selecting the text and then changing the selected portion of the text.

What i want to do is, when there is no text selected, but the fontDialog-Button has been pressed and the desired font is chosen, then the effect will go on all text in the RTF, the same goes to Coloring

Comment: anything tried yet ?

Comment: You need to __temporarily__ select the whole text and apply the styling. Then de-select.

Comment: @Felix D.minor things that Logical would work but since im a starter i might have just written them wrong or overall my logic is flawed

Comment: @TaW That's one way, but i want to do it so where No text is selected and then by pressing the font/colorDialog button it would apply it to all text

Comment: That is what I wrote. Note the  _temporarily_ !!

Comment: @TaW I dont want to select the Text  **at all** it should work through code
so if no text selected
but the desired font is chosen through fontdialog and then pressed OK
all text will be change to that font
**without selecting any text** 
PS: I dont see how this is a duplicate to the presumed post, that post does not answer my question

Comment: you can select the text in the code by setting `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` property, then unselect it after you have finished assigning the colour. This is what TaW meant

Comment: It is a duplicate because the answer(s) show how you can select Text in code and then style it. To select all write: `.....if (xxxDlg...) {int lastPos = rtb.SelectionStart;rtb.SelectionStart=0;rtb.Selection.Length=rtb.Text.Length; rtb.SelectionFont/Color=...;rtb.SelectionLength=0; rtb.SelectionStart=lastPos;` Note how I deselect all and store/restore the cursor position!

Comment: Oh my goodness, apologizes for my ignorance, now I understand what you meant.
Huge thank you for your patience!